# Why it appears an error even if I have a try and except?

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

```
def temperature_def(tem):       
try:
    if tem >= 34 and tem <= 38:
        return tem
    else:
        print("You can not enter the list!")
        quit()
except:
    print("Enter a number!")
    quit()

pearson1 = People_class((input("Name and Surname (with out accents): ").lower()), int(input("Age: ")),
        covid_status_def(input("Someone close to you either has covid or had it? ").lower().strip()),
                    temperature_def(float(input("What is your temperature in degrees? "))))
```

Here im trying to get a number for the if statement, I am taking the input in the last line.

The try and except should recognise if a number is not inputted (no idea if that is a word), and should do as it follows, but, when I type something that is not a number, it appears the error.

To clarify im doing a list and the "float(input(..." can not be moved (as far as I know).

Thanks in advance and happy holidays :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because you are explicitly trying to convert the user input to float:

```
temperature_def(float(input("What is your temperature in degrees? ")))
```

You should remove the `float` from above and pass the input without doing any explicit conversion. If the input was incorrect, the `try-except` defined in your method will handle it.

Edit: Since you removed the float convesion from `input`, you now have to put it inside the `try` block:

```
try:
    temp = float(temp)
    if tem >= 34 and tem <= 38:
         return tem
    else:
        print("You can not enter the list!")
        quit()
except:
    print("Enter a number!")
    quit()
```

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted. @David